# Why is my partial view not found using ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

Ive been following an example from a book of how to use the ajax to load a partial view in an existing webpage, but cant get it working.

Chrome's element inspectors tells me that the file can not be found (404), but when i navigate to the page manaualy, it loads fine.

Here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
   {
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Hello";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult HelloWorld()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Hello World";
        return PartialView();
    }

    }
}
```

Here is my main view:

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>index></title>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="divMessage">@ViewBag.Message</div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Refresh", "HelloWorld", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divMessage", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my partial view:

```
@ViewBag.Message
```

Can anybody suggest any reasons why this is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the Ajax call to be a POST, while the PartialView method is [HttpGet]
Change either the ajax call to "GET" or the method to [HttpPost]

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your method

```
public PartialViewResult HelloWorld()
 {
    ViewBag.Message = "Hello World";
    return PartialView();
 }
```

to `[HttpPost]` , as your ajax call makes a Post call.

Or change your ajax call to make a `GET` call.